# How do I stop a html textbox from refreshing on enter key?

Tags: html, textbox, enter, page-refresh

I just want to ask how can I stop my html textbox from refreshing when I press enter.

```
<div id="topSearchBox">
   <input id="Text1" type="text" value="search..."/>
   <img id="topSearchBoxIcon" alt="search buttom" src="~Images/Search-32x32.png" width="18px" height="18px" />
</div>
```

I have a script that tells it to do some thing else, but after the script has completed it refreshes the page anyway.

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) { // enter
            Search();
        }
    });
```

I've read a bit on it, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return false in the event to stop the default event (submit) taking place. This is assuming that the submit event is being triggered.

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { // enter
        Search();
        return false; //this will stop the default event triggering 
    }
});
```

You could also put it outside of a form (if it's inside).

**Note** - Also, it's better if you bound the event to your input directly.

```
$('#Text1').keyup();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) { // enter
    Search();
    return false; //you can also say e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: This works, thanks... Strange, late time I tried this it didn't work! Thanks any way.

Answer (score 1):

If I well understood, maybe the page refresh because you may have a submit input (or button) after to the input text field so when you hit the enter key you also send the form itself.

try to stop the propagation of the event with

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { // enter
        e.stopPropagation();
        Search();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have answered it here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16016122/1047337
It's about having only one text box in the form.