# Stop page refreshing when 'enter' is pressed in input text element

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to stop a webpage from refreshing completely when the enter button is pressed in a input text element?

I'm looking to create a search field that I can get the text from when enter is pressed to filter objects and only display the ones that contain text from the search field.

I've tried the following to try and catch the enter button but it does not work.

```
function setupSearchField() {
    document.getElementById("searchField").onKeyDown = function(event) {
        var holder;
        if (window.event) {
            holder = window.event.keyCode;
        } else {
            holder = event.which;
        }
        keyPressed(holder);
    }
}

function keyPressed(key) {
    if (key == 13) {
        event.cancelBubble = true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You say `event.cancelBubble = true` in `keyPressed()`, but there's no `event` in `keyPressed()`—that was in the `onKeyDown` callback!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the input element is inside a form, and that form is not actually being submitted to the server, remove the form.

The reason your code doesn't work is becaue the `onkeydown` event should be in lowercase, and you aren't actually returning something in it (try `return keyPressed(holder);` - or just move the `keyPressed` function's code into `setupSearchField`, since it seems kind of pointless to me to have it as a separate function).

Answer (score 2):

This happens when there is only one text input, regardless of whether your button (if any) has type="submit" or not. It's documented here.
http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2
So, as suggested by other people earlier, you then have to simply stop this default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Is your search field inside a  element ? Then hitting 'enter' fires a submit event to the form element.

In this case you could process your filtering by defining onsubmit on the form element.

```
<form id="searchForm">
    <input type="text" name="search" />
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById('searchForm').onsubmit = function() {
        var searchValue = this.search.value;
        // process
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Something like this maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following javascript code to your Visualforce page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function stopRKey(evt) 
{
   var evt=(evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
   var node=(evt.target)?evt.target:((evt.srcElement)?evt.srcElement:null);
   if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text")) {return false;}
}

document.onkeypress = stopRKey;
</script>
```